# Is it possible to output an Enum's options as its string value rather than its int value?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

So, I have a class defined as such...

```
public class Foo
{
    public Options Bar {get;set;}
}

public enum Options 
{
    Option1,
    Option2
}
```

When I use the JsonSchemaGenerator to generate its schema I get the following output...

```
var generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator();
return generator.Generate(typeof(Foo), false);

{
  "type": "object",
  "properties" : {
      "Bar": {                 
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0,1]
       }
   }
}
```

I understand this is accurate, however I was wondering what's the most elegant way of outputting the Bar property as type string with its possible string values.

I have tried the Json Attribute **[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]** and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @bradley-uffner any ideas?

Comment: Could this be of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719779/generate-schema-using-stringenumconverter

Comment: Thanks @RavB I was looking for something simpler, perhaps out of the box

Comment: I was just about to send my answer to this question. So please reopen or should I post to the old question instead?1 I find this question better asked.

Comment: @pmeyer there you go then... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39083517/1061668