# Properties With [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] Not Being Set As String In Schema

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I am using https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema.
When trying to convert 
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public FooType BlahType { get; set; }

I get the following in the Json schema:
"BlahType": {
      "type": "integer",
      "enum": [
        0,
        1
      ]
    }

Comment: Duplicate?  [Generate schema using StringEnumConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25719779/3744182).  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39083517) suggests using [`StringEnumGenerationProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_StringEnumGenerationProvider.htm), have you tried that?  You don't show your code so I don't know for sure.

Comment: Yes. it's a duplicate, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/508Yu5.