# Correct way to define Array of Enums in Newtonsoft Json schema generation

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, jsonschema

I have a c# class like below which I use to generate JSON schema using Newtonsoft library. I am having trouble generating the array of enums correctly. Can someone help me with this?

Here is the class code.

```
public class Building
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(BuildingZone))]
    public string[] Zone { get; set; }   // How should I declare this, so my jsonschema generator generates an Array of Enum values
    //public BuildingZone[] Zone { get; set; } 
}

public enum BuildingZone
{
    Residential,
    Commercial,
    Industrial
}
```

Below JSON Schema is generated for the above class,

```
"type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 100
    },
    "phoneNumber": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "phone"
    }, 
    "zone": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": [
          "string",
          "null"
        ]
      }
    },
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "phoneNumber",
    "zone",
  ]
}
```

However, I am expecting something like this for the zone parameter.

```
"zone": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["Residential", "Commercial", "Industrial"]
    }
}
```

Update:
Using StringEnumConverter like below worked for one of my cases.

```
[JsonProperty("Zone",ItemConverterType=typeof(StringEnumConverter))] 
public BuildingZone[] Zone { get; set; }
```

But the same doesn't work for the other parameter. The other enum is very similar to the one that is working. Calling the enum from external library and creating JSON schema. I tried

```
[JsonProperty("PMType", ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public PMType[] pmtype { get; set; }
```

and it generates

```
"PMType": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
```

Not sure what I am missing in this. I verified the PMType enum has expected values in the library. Is there a way I can debug this to find root cause?

Comment: Are you bound to Newtonsoft, or is using another library for JSON Schema support an option?

Comment: Something like `[JsonProperty("Zone", ItemConverterType=typeof(StringEnumConverter))] public BuildingZone[] Zone { get; set; } ` should give you an array of the string representation of the enum. This isn't a flags enum you could have the same enum value multiple times?

Comment: @Ralf : I tried your way to use StringEnumConverter and I am able to see the enum now. But the type of items is integer and the enum is a list of numbers. "items": { "type": "integer", "enum": [ 0,1,2]}   Is there a way I can retrieve the string from the enum instead of the integer? The enum in my code comes from a library and I cannot modify the enum like adding annotations to it. Can I change something in the client side so I can retrieve the string from the enum?

Comment: That's actually what the StringEnumConverter does or should do. Mapping between string and enum. Seeing the backing value of the enum is the default behavior when serializing so somehow your attribute has been ignore.

Comment: @Ralf : Is there a way to debug this? Because there are two places I use this strategy. It works on one but doesn't create enum value for the other

Comment: @Rafl: Updated the post with the details

Comment: Maybe show also how you called the JsonSerializer. Getting type properties alongside the actually property is not standard behavior so you have used custom settings.

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39083517/3744182) by [Mikko Viitala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061668/mikko-viitala) to [Generate schema using StringEnumConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25719779/3744182)?  It looks like it answers your question precisely.

Comment: Also be sure you are using [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) and not the obsolete classes from [`Newtonsoft.Json.Schema`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema.htm) that are built into core Newtonsoft.  The latter are no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to add

```
generator.GenerationProviders.Add(new StringEnumGenerationProvider());
```

this is a full example of code:

```
var obj = new Building(){
        Name = "ccc",
        PhoneNumber = "1112223333",
        Zone = BuildingZone.Commercial,
    };

    JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
    generator.GenerationProviders.Add(new StringEnumGenerationProvider());//!!!!!
    JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Building));
    Console.Write( schema.ToString());
```

so result would be :

[image]
and a class set:

```
public class Building
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] //!!!!!
    public BuildingZone Zone { get; set; }  
}
```