# Generated JSON invalid according to its own schema

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, jsonschema

I'm generating a schema for my class like this.

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new() 
  { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
JSchema dtoSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(SomeDto));
File.WriteAllText("dto.schema.json", dtoSchema.ToString());
```

The classes in the DTO are as follows.

```
class SomeDto
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Occasion { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<Key, SubDto> Data { get; set; } = default!;
}

enum Key { Donkey, Monkey, Honky }

class SubDto
{
  public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
  public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using those to create a serialization on of that structure to the drive.

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
  TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
  { Modifiers = { JsonPropertyInfoExtensions.AddTypedConverters } },
  PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
  PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
  WriteIndented = true
};
string output = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto, options);
File.WriteAllText("dto.example.json", output);
```

Then, elsewhere, at a location where said schema file resides next to the actual JSON file created based on the exactly same DTO, I validate the contents like this.

```
string data = File.ReadAllText("dto.example.json");
string schema = File.ReadAllText("dto.schema.json");
JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(data);
JSchema jsonSchema = JSchema.Parse(schema);
bool valid = jsonData.IsValid(jsonSchema, out IList<string> issues);
```

It tells me it's invalid. The issues mentioned are due to the key type inconsistency. While the announced type in the schema of the key (being an enum) is *number*, the actual content of the JSON is a *string*.

> Invalid type. Expected Number but got String. Path 'data.Donkey.value', line 7...
> Invalid type. Expected Number but got String. Path 'data.Monkey.value', line 11...

As the actual requirement of the consumer goes, I need to have the readable name, not the numeric value. At the moment, I could probably make that change manually altering the schema but that's... baaad. In so many ways...

Is there a way to produce schema knowing that the keys corresponding to the keys will be strings and not numbers?

Comment: Hard to say, you could have some sort of JsonConverter applied somewhere (maybe even in `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`) that causes the serialized JSON to differ from the schema created via reflection.  Enums are a common cause of this, make sure you are using (or not using) `StringEnumConverter` consistently.  See e.g. [Generate schema using StringEnumConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25719779) or [Cannot generate schema of type that uses `[JsonConverter]` class attribute #51](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/51#issuecomment-251253225).

Comment: *How can I leard what's invalid?* -- Use the overload [`Extensions.IsValid(JToken, JsonSchema, out IList<String>)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Extensions_IsValid_1.htm).  The last argument `out IList<string> errorMessages` will contain error messages explaining where the violations were encountered.

Comment: Does that answer your question?  Because as it is, absent a [mcve] there's no way to definitely answer your question.

Comment: @dbc Let me apply your comment about the output list with errors. Somehow, intelisense didn't show it sufficiently apparently to me. I missed that. I'll update the question with an adapted version of my actual DTO to fetch the exact issue.

Comment: @dbc Great suggestion. Now, I can concretize my question much better. The minimum sample is in the edited body - just remove all text and run it to see the result.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your problem with .NET 7.0.5, Newtonsoft.Json Version=13.0.0.0 and Newtonsoft.Json.Schema Version=3.0.0.0 and I cannot -- the JSON file generated by System.Text.Json is validated successfully by Json.NET schema, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ONPMWj.  But your question doesn't share the code for `JsonPropertyInfoExtensions.AddTypedConverters` so maybe the problem is there.  Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc First of all - my appies for the late reply: buttload of urgent work and sickness. That said, I believe you're pointing in the right direction. There was some global setting I've not been aware of. So the actual reason was PICNIC but I still like the question/answer since it helps in a way to detect the root cause. I leave it up to you to let it stay or be flagged as closeable. Thanks for you effort, too. It did helped (even if another way than expected) and I learned something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fan of answering my own questions, I still prefer that over just leaving it as-is.

The suggestion made in comments pointed out a way to investigate the exact reason(s) of the validation failure. Once found out **where** it breaks, it was straightforward (if not easy) to resolve the issue.

```
Extensions.IsValid(JToken, JsonSchema, out IList<String>)
```

The last argument, `out IList<string> errorMessages` will contain error messages explaining where the violations were encountered. (Credit goes to @dbc.)